# React.js form values not refreshing

Tags: javascript, forms, components

I have a page that has a side nav with elements that on being clicked brings up different forms for each element. I'm using react.js for it

I'm reusing the same components for form rendering for each element.

Eg.

```
Home -> Brings up a form with form inputs such as Location, Price

Car  -> Brings up a form with inputs such as Make, Model
```

However if I enter a value for Location (Home form) then when I click Car,  the entry for my Home form remains the same form my previous input. I am not sure how to reuse the components the right way so that the form entry values for each element is blank when clicked

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a key problem

http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/